# Python - What is correct way to copy a class object A which contains an array of class objects B

Tags: python, list

I want to copy an array of class objects and update the original array without the copied array changing also. See this code which illustrates the problem. I do not want B to change when I change A:

## Copy array of class objects test

```
import copy

class B:
  val=0
  p=40

class A:
  g=[]

  def __init__(self):
      self.g.append(B())
      self.g.append(B())                                                       
        
def main():
  a=A()
  print("a.g[0] is " + str(a.g[0].val) + " , " + str(a.g[0].p))
  print("a.g[1] is " + str(a.g[1].val) + " , " + str(a.g[1].p))
  print("Copying a to b")
  b=copy.deepcopy(a)
  print ("Now updating a[0]")
  a.g[0].val=25
  print("a.g[0] now is " + str(a.g[0].val) + " , " + str(a.g[0].p))
  print("a.g[1] now is " + str(a.g[1].val) + " , " + str(a.g[1].p))
  print("Now printing which which was copied from original a")
  print("b.g[0] is " + str(b.g[0].val) + " , " + str(b.g[0].p))
  print("b.g[1] is " + str(b.g[1].val) + " , " + str(b.g[1].p))


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: Did you mean `def __init__(self): self.g = []`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you define `val` ,`p`, and `g` as class variables by declaring them directly within the class.

When you declare a class variable, that variable is related directly to the class itself and affects all instances of the class. An instance variable gets created with all objects of that class, but the value can vary from object to object. Imagine a class called `wallet` that has an attribute called `money`. Each `wallet` starts with `1000` for money, but they gain and lose money independently of each other. If I add 100 to one `wallet`, all the others are changed. A class variable behaves differently. Lets say I gave `wallet` a class variable called `currency` and set it to `"USD"`. If I change this variable to `"CAD"`, now ALL `wallet` objects will have their `currency` attribute set to `"CAD"`, including the ones who are created already.

The solution is to make them instance variables and assigning the values underneath `__init__` as `self.<insert>` rather than just `<insert>`. You can see an example of the change below. When I ran your `main()` function with the changes I made to the classes below, the changes made to `A` were not reflected in `B`.

A good rule of thumb is to always default to declaring your variables inside of `__init__` because it will force you to think about how a class variable is behaving when you use it.

```
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val=0
        self.p=40

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.g=[]
        self.g.append(B())
        self.g.append(B())
```

Comment: This is exactly right. Maybe add a phrase to clarify that the difference between class and instance variables is that class variables bound to different instances all refer to the same object?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I put an explanation of the difference that should hopefully make the distinction easy to remember for anyone else stumbling across this.

Comment: Thank you. It becomes very clear when you realise that a class level variable is in effect “global” .  I had intended to use these classes to solve a recursive problem. A class level variable will enable me to record the recursion depth so you have solved two problems for the price of one. Many thanks